# how broker() function in trait SendsPasswordResetEmails return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel 5.3, In Forgot Password Controller, there is `Trait SendsPasswordResetEmails`

if you go to it's definition, there is function called `broker()`, it returns `contract` of type `\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker`

if you go to `\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker` , there is no function declaration with the name of `broker()`

and not even in it's derived class `\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker.php`

I saw it was present in `\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBrokerManager.php`

**Question**: Can you kindly tell how `broker()` function in `trait SendsPasswordResetEmails` return `\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Password` facade returns an instance of `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBrokerManager`.

Within `PasswordBrokerManager` there is a method called `broker`. It is the method `broker` that then returns an instance of `PasswordBroker`.

Basically, this:

```
Password::broker();
```

is just another way to write:

```
$manager = new PasswordBrokerManager();
return $manager->broker();
```

You are returning the results of that method not the method itself.

The way `Facades` work (in a nutshell).

Facades provide a way for you to get a class without having to `new` it up (they have a few other benefits as well but we don't need to go in to them). 
You'll notice that you will always call a method from a Facade statically, this is because there is a `magic method` in the facade called `__callStatic` which will be called if there isn't a method in that class with that name (and the method is called statically).
This then uses the `getFacadeRoot` and `getFacadeAccessor` methods to find out what is actually meant to called. It then gets an instance of that call and calls this method on it (in this example `broker`).

If you go to `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider` you'll see:

```
 $this->app->singleton('auth.password', function ($app) {
        return new PasswordBrokerManager($app);
    });
```

The above is telling `Laravel` to register `auth.password` as an instance `PasswordBrokerManager`. Then in the `Password` Facade class you'll see:

```
protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
{
    return 'auth.password';
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @RossWilson: I saw `Password Facade`, there are few private constants and a protected method only.  Am I missing anything?

Comment: @Helper I've updated my answer to give a bit more detail of how `Facade`s work.

Comment: I was using trait in Controller. Controller already has a Constructor. Due to some reasons, I needed constructor for dependency Injection in `trait` also. Unfortunately this is not possible to execute constructor in trait when controller already has constructor. **Question**: Should I create a Facade which will return contract in trait and thus instead of Constructor dependency injection in trait, we could get contract through Facade in trait? Is it a good practice?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Also, with that being a separate question (and going outside of the scope of this one) you should create another post for it. That being said are you happy that my answer answers your question for this post?

Comment: that's a very brief yet clear illustration about facade !

Answer (score 2):

Here's the method `broker` in the `SendsPasswordResetEmails` **trait**:

```
/**
 * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
 */
public function broker()
{
    return Password::broker();
}
```

The method makes a static call to the `broker()` method in the `PasswordBrokerManager` class. The `Password` here is a `Facade` and in that `Facade`, you'll see this method:

```
/**
 * Get the registered name of the component.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
{
    return 'auth.password';
}
```

This simply returns `auth.password` string which is ultimately resolved to `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBrokerManager`. You can see it in the docs under [Facade Class Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/facades#facade-class-reference).

And finally, in the `PasswordBrokerManager` class, you have the `broker()` method:

```
/**
 * Attempt to get the broker from the local cache.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
 */
public function broker($name = null)
{
    $name = $name ?: $this->getDefaultDriver();

    return isset($this->brokers[$name])
                ? $this->brokers[$name]
                : $this->brokers[$name] = $this->resolve($name);
}
```

Comment: I checked the article already. Can you kindly help me to understand that how `auth.password`  resolved to `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBrokerManager` ? `getFacadeAccessor` method just returns string.